# To Find the registry of SQL Server 2005 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

i want the registry value SQL Server 2005 Management Studio (because our application is dependent;) before installing our application i am checking whether SQL Server 2005 Management Studio is present or not and i have cross checked that for SQL Server Management Studio with Express Edition it is having different registry value and for SQL Server Management Studio Developer Edition it is having different registry value;
All i want is a common registry for SQL Server 2005 Management Studio so that i can check it before installation of my product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL 2005 SSMS stores its settings at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell
```

SQL 2008 SSMS stores its settings at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell
```

Comment: Greetings Scott,

i cross verified the above registry settings, with what name it will be in this registry that is, under this 
KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell
with what will be the name of SSMS because in my system i am unable find it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this path, hope it helps:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\90\TOOLS\SETUP\PRODUCT CODE
```